# Drawing Multiple Guage charts at a time using Coregraphics

Tags: ios, xcode, charts, core-graphics, quartz-core

I'm working on charts using **CORE GRAPHICS** only. I've successfully completed drawing line charts, bar charts and single guage chart.

Now My requirement is 
[image: My requirement]

**But when i'm drawing in the context and i'm getting only one chart like this**

[image: What i got]
I've taken the percentages of the graphs in an array and using `for` loop, i've been drawing all the percentages in an array, But the ultimate result i'm getting is only one guage chart that is the last object in the array.

I've drawn these graphs using these [link](http://code4app.net/ios/Percentage-Circular/50cfec3d6803fa7442000001)

slightly changed the code and drawing charts like this

code i'm using to draw the guage chart is

first i'm calling the guagegraph(subclass of `UIView`) from my Viewcontroller

percentageArray contains percentages of each guage

```
percentageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"80", @"76", @"92", @"49", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < percentageArray.count; i++)
    {
        [guageGraph setPercent:[percentageArray[i] intValue] withIndex:i];
    }
```

then in guagegraph the below method

```
- (void)setPercent:(int)percent withIndex:(int)i
{
CGFloat floatPercent = percent / 100.0;
floatPercent = MIN(1, MAX(0, floatPercent));
percentLayer.percent = floatPercent;
percentLayer.i = i;
[self setNeedsLayout];
[percentLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

then calling the percentLayer class(subclass of `CALayer`) and drawing the context

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
[self DrawRight:ctx];
[self DrawLeft:ctx];

}
-(void)DrawRight:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, 160);

CGFloat delta = -toRadians(270 * percent);


CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);

CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, 135 - 5 - (15 * i), (3 * M_PI / 4), -delta);
CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, 150 - 5 - (15 * i), (3 * M_PI / 4) - delta, delta);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, center.x, center.y);

CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}

-(void)DrawLeft:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, 160);
CGFloat delta = toRadians(270 * (1 - percent));


CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor].CGColor);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);

CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, 135 - 5 - (15 * i), (M_PI / 4), -delta);
CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, 150 - 5 - (15 * i), (M_PI / 4) - delta, delta);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, center.x, center.y);

CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

`drawRight` method is to draw the orange colored one and `draw left` method to draw the grouptableviewbackground colored one.

when the loop starts, the first percentage chart is drawn, and when the second loop starts, the first drawn chart is overrided by the current loop percentage and the second chart is drawn, like this the last chart is only shown

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue lies here ->

```
 percentageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"80", @"76", @"92", @"49", nil];
 for (int i = 0; i < percentageArray.count; i++)
{
    [guageGraph setPercent:[percentageArray[i] intValue] withIndex:i];
}
```

I feel you should instead be adding them to an array. and display them once all objects have been drawn.

**EDIT**

**FIRST** 
lets make your `precentLayer` class display different color gauges. so add this bit of code to `-(void)drawRight`

```
CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
UIColor *randomColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

//update this line
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, randomColor.CGColor);
```

And See if maybe they are just overlapping each other if that is not the case...

============================================================================

**THEN** since there is only one view, try something like this.

```
percentageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"80", @"76", @"92", @"49", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < percentageArray.count; i++) {

    UIView *percentGauge =[self setPercent:[percentageArray[i] intValue] withIndex:i];

    //make background clear so we can see the guage behind it
    percentGauge.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

and make `-(void)setPercent: withIndex:` return a `UIView` so....

```
- (UIView *)setPercent:(int)percent withIndex:(int)i {
    CGFloat floatPercent = percent / 100.0;
    floatPercent = MIN(1, MAX(0, floatPercent));
    percentLayer.percent = floatPercent;
    percentLayer.i = i;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [percentLayer setNeedsDisplay];


    return self;
}
```

if that doesn't help any, you could upload the files you are using to dropbox and I can give it a shot.

Comment: well it sounds like `[guageGraph setPercent:[percentageArray[i] intValue] withIndex:i];` is setting the same view over and over while it runs this `for loop`. Is there only one `view` on the page? or do you have a `view` for each object inside of `percentageArray`?

Comment: there is only one view